# Mudar display de elementos em hover de outro elemento não funciona como deveria

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu quero mudar o display dos elementos com as classes .slide-prev e .slide-next. Como estou usando um plugin de slides, ele automaticamente cria os elementos de navegação fora da ul, então a única forma que a mudança de display funcionou foi com javascript. O problema é que não funcionou como deveria.

Quando eu passo o mouse por cima da div com a classe .intro-noticias os elementos aparecem, e quando saio eles somem, até aí tudo bem. O problema é quando eu passo o mouse por cima dos elementos .slide-prev e .slide-next, eles ficam tremendo, somem dependendo de onde a seta está e não ativam o hover.

Pode ser que eu deixei algo simples passar, mas realmente não encontrei, se alguém souber o que está ocasionando isso eu agradeço.

[Vídeo demonstrando o problema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsFqgij0RWE&feature=youtu.be)

Código:

```js
$(".intro-noticias").hover(function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "block");
}, function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
.intro-noticias {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.slide-prev {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

.slide-prev:after {
  content:"icon";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9.5px;
  left: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: url("img/icones/previous.png") left center no-repeat;
}

.slide-prev:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.slide-next {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 40px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: none;
}

.slide-next:after {
  content:"icon";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 9.5px;
  right: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: url("img/icones/next.png") right center no-repeat;
}

.slide-next:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <div class="intro-noticias"> 
          <div>
              <h2></h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="slide-prev">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="slide-next">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é que, quando o mouse entra nos elementos `.slide-prev` ou `.slide-next`, ele envia um `mouseleave` para o `.intro-noticias`, causando este *flicker*.

Uma possível solução seria, no *mouseleave*, descobrir qual elemento está entrando, e caso seja um daqueles botões, não fazer nada. Para isto, temos o `relatedTarget`, que, no *mouseleave*, aponta para o elemento que o mouse entrou.

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) (minha tradução):

> A propriedade somente leitura **MouseEvent.relatedTarget** é o alvo secundário para o evento, se houver algum. Isto é:
>
> ***mouseleave***
>
> *currentTarget*: O EventTarget que o mouse **entrou**.

Então, a seguinte alteração deve resolver o problema:

```
$(".intro-noticias").hover(function(e) {

    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "block");

}, function(e) {

    /* não esconder se estiver passando o mouse por cima dos botões */
    if (
        e.relatedTarget && 
        (
            e.relatedTarget.className === 'slide-prev' || 
            e.relatedTarget.className === 'slide-next'
        )
    ) return;

    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou

Comment: @GabrielSouza coloquei o código aqui e aparentemente desapareceu o problema https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/wdjc5mye/

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada se não é algo a mais?

Comment: Realmente, vou dar uma olhada no meu código

Comment: Adicionando uma div funcionou com seu código também, mas usei um mais simples

Answer (score 0):

Eu adicionei uma div com a classe intro-slides, modifiquei o script e funcionou

```js
$(".intro-slides").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "block");
});
$(".intro-slides").mouseleave(function() {
    $('.slide-prev,.slide-next').css("display", "none");
});
```

```html
<div class="intro-slides">
 <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="intro-noticias">  
          <div>
              <h2></h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" class="slide-prev">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="slide-next">Next</a>
</div>
```